# SQL Server на Fedora Linux

Tags: sql, linux, sql-server, fedora

пытался поставить sql server, делал все по документации, но при установке выдает такую ошибку, openssl поставлен, все что нарыл сделал, ошибка не уходит, помогите!!!

```
Error: cannot find libcrypto.so in any system library search paths. Ensure that a file or symbolic link named 'libcrypto.so' exists in the system library search paths. To resolve this error, a symbolic link to the 'libcrypto.so' library can be placed in the '/opt/mssql/lib/' directory.
Error: cannot find libssl.so in any system library search paths. Ensure that a file or symbolic link named 'libssl.so' exists in the system library search paths. To resolve this error, a symbolic link to the 'libssl.so' library can be placed in the '/opt/mssql/lib/' directory.
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: PAL initialization failed. Error: 102
```

Comment: один из вариантов проблемы. что требуемая библиотека есть, но более высокой версии, несовместимой с требуемой. для таких больших программ требуется полное соответствие требованиям, указанным в документации. вплоть до неприменения обновлений.